# How to modify Json file from power shell script gcp output

Tags: json, powershell, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, powershell-2.0

I have a GCP script below mentioned, running in power shell

```
$cred = gcloud auth print-access-token
$headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $cred" }
Invoke-WebRequest `
    -Method GET `
    -Headers $headers `
    -Uri "https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/v1/projects/source-project/instances/source-instance/backupRuns" | Select-Object -Expand Content
```

getting output from above script like below

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\urllib3\connectionpool.py:979: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'oauth2.googleapis.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  warnings.warn(
{
  "kind": "sql#backupRunsList",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "sql#backupRun",
      "status": "SUCCESSFUL",
      "enqueuedTime": "2023-01-11T00:33:21.903Z",
      "id": "1673391600000",
      "startTime": "2023-01-11T00:33:21.949Z",
      "endTime": "2023-01-11T00:38:47.459Z",
      "type": "AUTOMATED",
      "windowStartTime": "2023-01-10T23:00:00Z",
      "instance": "instance",
      "selfLink": "https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project/instances/instance/backupRuns/1673391600000",
      "location": "us",
      "backupKind": "SNAPSHOT"
    },
    {
      "kind": "sql#backupRun",
      "status": "SUCCESSFUL",
      "enqueuedTime": "2023-01-09T23:36:39.776Z",
      "id": "1673305200000",
      "startTime": "2023-01-09T23:36:39.826Z",
      "endTime": "2023-01-09T23:42:05.542Z",
      "type": "AUTOMATED",
      "windowStartTime": "2023-01-09T23:00:00Z",
      "instance": "instance ",
      "selfLink": "https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project/instances/instance/backupRuns/1673305200000",
      "location": "us",
      "backupKind": "SNAPSHOT"
    },
```

And I have a JSON file in the same folder like below

```
{
  "restoreBackupContext":
  {
    "backupRunId": 1673391600000,
    "project": "project",
    "instanceId": "instance"
  }
}
```

I want to update " "id": " each time from output to json automatically while running first script
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RyqN.png)

The " "id": "  value each time getting new.

Let me know how to achieve it

thanks

Comment: Update ID with what? I don't understand what you're asking and what you're having trouble with

Comment: I have " "id": " value  in output is "1673391600000" its copied manually to JSON file "backupRunId": 1673391600000,I want this automatically update from script